# Logcat shows the data read but when put into edit text, it doesnt show in fragment

Tags: php, android

I'm using volley request in android and also using sharedpreferences as user logs in. I use this code to pass in another php to get data for editing the data.

```
@Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("id", getId);
                    return super.getParams();
        }
```

getId is initialized as String getId; and making it to

```
getId = user.get(sessionManager.ID);
```

now my logcat tells me this

```
{"read":[],"success":"0","message":"error"}
```

this is my php file for receiving the thrown id.

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$id = $_POST['id'];

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","id7508046_root","123123123as","id7508046_isalon");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_id=$id";

$response = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$result = array();
$result['read'] = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($response) === 1){

    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)){
    $h['name']          = $row['name'];
    $h['phone_number']  = $row['phone_number'];
    $h['gender']        = $row['gender'];
    $h['address']       = $row['address'];
    $h['occupation']    = $row['occupation'];
    $h['birth_date']    = $row['birth_date'];
    $h['user_type']     = $row['user_type'];

    array_push($result["read"], $h);

    $result["success"] = "1";
    echo json_encode($result);
    }

}else{

    $result["success"] = "0";
    $result["message"] = "error";
    echo json_encode($result);

}

}


?>
```

This is the code of putting the data retrieved to the edit text.

```
    package com.example.kristopher.isalon.Profile;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.kristopher.isalon.R;
import com.example.kristopher.isalon.SessionManage.SessionManager;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SideProfileFragment extends  Fragment{

    private static final String TAG = SideProfileFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private EditText name, birthDate, address, occupation, gender, number;


    SessionManager sessionManager;
    String getId;
    private static final String URL_READ = "http://isalonbyageeks.000webhostapp.com/readDetail.php";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sideprofile, container, false);

        name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        birthDate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.userBirthDate);
        address = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.userAddress);
        occupation = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.userOccupation);
        gender = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.userGender);
        number = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.userNumber);

        return view;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        sessionManager = new SessionManager(getActivity());
        sessionManager.checkLogin();

        HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetail();
        getId = user.get(sessionManager.ID);


    }
    private void getUserDetail(){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loadingws...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_READ,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.i(TAG, response);

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("read");

                            if(success.equals("1")){
                                for(int i = 0; 1 < jsonArray.length();i++){

                                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String strName = object.getString ("name");
                                    String strNumber = object.getString("phone_number");
                                    String strGender = object.getString("gender");
                                    String strAddress = object.getString("address");
                                    String strOccupation = object.getString("occupation");
                                    String strBirthDate = object.getString("birth_date");

                                    name.setText(strName);
                                    birthDate.setText(strBirthDate);
                                    address.setText(strAddress);
                                    number.setText(strNumber);
                                    gender.setText(strGender);
                                    occupation.setText(strOccupation);



                                }
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error Reading Detail" +e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error Reading Detail" +error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("id", getId);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        getUserDetail();
    }

}
```

This is what the logcat shows, saying the data is retrieved.

```
{"read":[{"name":"Iam weak","phone_number":"09476542875","gender":"Male","address":"Didto St.","occupation":"Weak naman ko","birth_date":"09\/12\/2012","user_type":"Client"}],"success":"1","message":"success"}
```

Comment: Can you check $result["message"] = "$sql"; and see sql query correct or not?

Comment: thank you for replying sir. i have updated my php. it did get the value of the ID and my query seems fine i dont really understand where did i go wrong :( its been hours.

Comment: i also updated the h array and put some names on them because i was lacking it

Comment: Did you check MYSQL connection?          if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

Comment: sir!I have the data now. the data is retrieved as shown in logcat. but now my problem is putting it in the edit text from the fragment.

name.setText("strName"); but then it doesn't show.

Comment: We must see the code. What is "name"? Where is editText? Can you write the code please?

Comment: Okay sir, ill edit my post

Comment: I have edited my post now sir and that is my current code on progress. I hope it gets out as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is here (You wrote 1, instead of i):

```
for(int i = 0; 1 < jsonArray.length();i++)
```

So you can't get in to if statement.

Instead, write:

```
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++)
```

Very small error, and easy to miss :(

Comment: OH.... MY..... GOD....... sir. i dont really know what i've been drinking all this time. i dont really know what can I say. i dont really undestand what my mind is at right now :( THANK YOU SO SO SO SO MUCH!